# htaccess use alias for term

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress website which has `typee` registered as a taxonomy. I need to use `type` instead of `typee` and preserve the content too. Can I use any httaccess rewrite rule to achieve this?

To clear out things, the url rewrite should be something like

`http://someurl.com/typee/product-name` to `http://someurl.com/type/product-name`

Answer (score 0):

If you know where your taxonomy is registered, you can rewrite its slug.
You can check [register_taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) function. It accept `rewrite` param that you can use.
So you code will be something similar to the following

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'type' )
```

Then do not forget to rebuild you permalinks

Comment: Hi Stanimir, WordPress has `type` registered as a reserved word so I cannot use it from backend. That's why I wanted to implement this on htaccess level